# CSS3 - Unable to make ribbon grow\shrink according to text length

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a css ribbon with dynamic text, though I'm having troubles making the `:after` element grow\shrink as its parent element.
[CodePen code here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJRKYX)
For example, HTML:

```
<span class="ribbon hidden-xs">
  <strong class="ribbon-content ng-binding" id="ribbonText">this is a dummy text</strong>
</span>

<span class="ribbon hidden-xs">
  <strong class="ribbon-content ng-binding" id="ribbonText">this is a dummy text this is a dummy text this is a dummy text this is a dummy text this is a dummy text this is a dummy text</strong>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.ribbon {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  left: 120px;
  background: rgba(224, 147, 59, 1);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  right: 5px;
  top: 40px;
  padding: 14px 7px;
  z-index: 99;
  min-height: 72px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.ribbon:after {
  right: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-right-color: rgba(224, 147, 59, 1);
  border-width: 36px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -36px;
}

.ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #999 transparent transparent transparent;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm having hard time understanding what's wrong. What should happen? What isn't working?

Comment: The problem is that the `:after` element stays the same size. I need it to grow or shrink according to the size of `.ribbon`.

Comment: But you added a fixed size to :after element, you have border-width: 36px; styles and no matter how parent's size is changing - :after element will be the same 36px

Comment: Thats the point, I dont know how I can make these values dynamic. `border-width` cannot be set to 100%;

Comment: @undroid you can use a bit of JS code for it. If jQuery solution is OK for you, I can add a code-snippet which will make this border-width dynamic =)

Comment: Thanks Nat, but it's an angular app, no jQuery allowed. Vanilla JS is an option